# HTML from database is displayed as plain text

Tags: node.js, express

I have a webserver running on `NodeJS` and `ExpressJS`. As template engine I am using `EJS`.
There's a database where I store posts and some of these include html tags such as **<b>****<i>****<u>**. Before the posts are uploaded to the database; They are **trim()** & **escape()** -ed. Also unwanted tags are stripped away.

The problem is that when I fetch posts from db, send it to the client over expressjs `render('template', {options:__, x: _, y: _})` method, the html is not displayed as its supposed to be. It is displayed as plaintext like so:  `<b>test</b>` instead of **test**.

## Main.js ( script which fetches posts from db )

```
const express = require('express');
const sql = require('sql');


module.exports = {
    runScript: function(callback){

        sql.prepareQuery('SELECT `posts`.*, `accounts`.`firstname`, `accounts`.`lastname`, `accounts`.`username` FROM `posts` LEFT JOIN `accounts` ON `posts`.`author_id`=`accounts`.`id` ORDER BY `posts`.`time` DESC LIMIT 20',
        {}, function(error, results){
            let variables = {
                posts:results
            }

            callback(variables);
        });

    }
}
```

## Router for main page

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    try {
        let pageCore = require(__dirname + "/backend/main.js");


        pageCore.runScript(function(obj){
            res.set({'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});

            res.locals.posts = obj.posts;
            res.locals.timeParser = require('timeParser');

            res.render('index', {
                title:"Express",
                pageToDisplay: "main.ejs"
            });
        });


    } catch(e){
        console.log("WTF??", e);
        res.send(e);
    }
});
```

## Main.EJS (html part)

```
<div class="postBody">
    <%= decodeURIComponent(posts[i].content) %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a print vs eval thing. Try switching your ejs to this instead.

```
<div class="postBody">
    <%- decodeURIComponent(posts[i].content) %>
</div>
```

Comment: *_Pxhxjakshxk_* _Mind explodes_ ... You saved the day. Thank you master.

Comment: Ha, definitely no master, just got lucky, but happy to help!